# Vb.net regex get data between html tag with class

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, class

I'm a complete newbie on regular expressions. I need to find the data between the following html tags in an entire html document. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<b class="boldtitle"> This is a title </b>
<span id="desc"> 45data45 </span>
```

I need the first regex to provide me the data " `This is a title` "

and the second one to provide "`45data45`".

Thanks in advance as it would help me do a comparitive study helping me more.

Comment: Research Regular Expressions and attempt to do this yourself first, parsing an entire HTML Document wont be as easy as just incorporating Regex. You will need much more than that depending on the complexity of the Document. Get some code going and if you get stuck then ask with some code to back you up.

Comment: I've spent hours researching this unable to match the equal to and double quotes. It's just that I didnt know how best to ask, this being my first question

Comment: Maybe VB has some Dom utility?

Comment: @user3329528 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will find both your tags as long as they look exactly as you told:

```
<(b\s*class="boldtitle"|span\s*id="desc")>(.*)</(b|span)>
```

And at this link you fill find an outstanding good regex tester:
[Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)